# How to keep one part of a sentence Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, bots, sentence

I would like to keep one part of a sentence to put it in the arg of a function like this :

```
var sen1 = "Hello this is my email"
var final = "this is my email"
```

I'm a begginer with Node.js and JS in general. I've heard about the function RegExp but i don't know how to use it to remove the `Hello` from the `sen1`.

Can anyone help me or suggest me ideas to do it ?

Comment: `var final = sen1.replace('Hello ', '');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need RegEx for this, you can simply use the String method `replace()` for this.

The syntax is as follows:

```
"".replace(<What you want to replace>, <by what you want to replace it>)
```

So you are looking for this:

```js
let sen1 = "Hello this is my email"
let final = sen1.replace("Hello ", "");

console.log(final);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working :) perfectly and that's so simple thank you !

Comment: Sure, glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via below RegEx.

```js
var sen1 = "Hello this is my email"

console.log(sen1.replace(/^\w+\s/, ""));
```

Explanation for RegEx - `^\w+\s`

- `^` means beginning of string
- `\w+` means group of characters(`\w`)
- `\s` means whitespace